# Table cell ignoring height

Tags: html, css, wordpress

**This is a live example only.**

We are migrating a website with some unique tables to Wordpress. On one of them the TD's are not aligning properly and ignoring any *height* rules we put on them, css or otherwise. All we've done is migrate the table over in it's original form, where it is displayed properly, but are getting weird bugs. Spent the last 4 hours trying to solve this one issue. Take a look at the ***second table*** at the following links:

[Proper working table](http://oceanlegends.com/padi-scuba-diving.shtml)

[Broken table](http://www.digitalreachagencydev.com/ocean-legends/recreational-diving/)

The heights of the above pieces should be precisely 7px, but instead are 16px when there is ***no padding or margin***.

Anyone have any ideas?

CSS

```css
/** Flow chart page **/

#padi_flowchart {
 width:580px !Important;
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
 color:#FFFFFF;
 background-image:url("/ocean-legends/wp-content/themes/Ocean%20Legends/Assets/img/padi_flowchart_background.jpg");
 background-postion:top left;
 background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
#padi_flowchart * {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}
#padi_flowchart a {
 color:#FFFFFF;
}
#padi_flowchart .fixwidth {
 height: 7px;
}
#padi_flowchart .fixwidth br {
 display: none;
}
#padi_flowchart .fixwidth img {
 width: 100% !Important;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix the 1st `table`. It's the browser default margin and padding values on the `ul` list cause that. This should fix it.

```
.course_box ul {
    padding: 0 0 0 16px; /* or your value */
    margin: 0;
}
```

To fix the 2nd `table` two ways I can think of:

1. Add `line-height: 0;` to the `td`. That should fix all, but be careful with the text if there is any inside.
2. make the top `img` `vertical-align: bottom;` and bottom `img` to `vertical-align: top;` in the table cells.

Comment: Second table below "PADI Course Curriculum & Master Scuba Diver Path"

Comment: OMG, totally ignored that one, will look and see if I can still help.

Comment: Updated the answer, suggested two possible solutions.

Comment: Thank you! That was a royal pain.